# Intel hda audio issue

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, oss

Pavucontrol don't see the intel sound card but alsamixer do, the sound work lightly at launch and stop, I need to be able to use my nvidia hdmi sound output when needed and the intel hda is my main sound so I need it working.

```
mike@Lenovo-Thinkstation-E31:~$ inxi -F
System:    Host: Lenovo-Thinkstation-E31 Kernel: 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: MATE 1.16.2  Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Machine:   Device: desktop System: LENOVO product: 255542U v: ThinkStation E31
           Mobo: LENOVO model: MAHOBAY
           UEFI: LENOVO v: 9SKT99AUS date: 06/30/2017
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GM107 [GeForce GTX 750]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 750/PCIe/SSE2
           GLX Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 NVIDIA Device 0fbc driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.9.0-9-amd64
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: @zillion I see you deleted an apparent self-answer recently, and have again edited your question to oblivion. What is your intention here? Should we close the question as "you no longer have the problem", or are you having trouble posting an answer, or what? We cannot continue with the malicious editing of an existing question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found out the timidity was blocking pulseaudio.
I uninstalled "timidity", and instantly pulseaudio found my intel soundcard.